# How to properly use malloc() and realloc() when pointing to a struct?

Tags: c, malloc, size, dynamic-arrays, realloc

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    char name;
    char surname;
    int month;
    int day;
} person;

person *ptr;
int action, number_of_friends=0, a, b, day, month;
char decision;

int main(void)
{
    ptr=(person*)malloc(sizeof(person));
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the data about the person number %d\n", number_of_friends+1);
        person entered_person;
        printf("Initial of the name: "); scanf(" %c", &entered_person.name);
        printf("Initial of the surname: "); scanf(" %c", &entered_person.surname);
        printf("The day of birth: "); scanf("%d", &entered_person.day);
        printf("And the month: "); scanf("%d", &entered_person.month);
        *(ptr+number_of_friends) = entered_person;
        printf("Do you want to add more friends? (y/n) ");
        scanf(" %c", &decision);
        if (decision=='n' || decision=='N') {
            break;
        }
        number_of_friends++;
        ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends);
    }
    number_of_friends++;
    person get_person;
    for (a=0; a<number_of_friends; a++)
    {
        get_person = *(ptr+a);
        printf("Person number %d\n", a+1);
        printf("Initial of the name: %c\n", get_person.name);
        printf("Initial of the surname: %c\n", get_person.surname);
        printf("The day of birth: %d\n", get_person.day);
        printf("And the month: %d\n\n", get_person.month);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it won't display the list of entered people correctly if the number of people is greater than... something like 5.

I believe this is connected with malloc() and realloc() (writing out-of-bounds?) but as a beginner I don't know how to solve that problem.

Comment: malloc doesn't care about structures. it only cares about how big of a memory chunk you want. to malloc, there's no difference between `malloc(2)` and `malloc(sizeof(int))` - it'll just see an integer passed in, and try to allocate a memory block of that size.

Comment: `ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends);` -> `ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends*sizeof(person));`

Comment: Dunno why backticks are not working...

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @EugeneSh. space....

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's it, thanks

Comment: Better: `other_ptr = realloc(ptr, number_of_friends * sizeof(*ptr));`.  In the event that `realloc()` fails, you then have some hope to avoid a memory leak because you have not clobbered the original pointer.

Comment: How do you expect the `name` and `surname` to each fit in a single char?

Comment: @rici I'm about to enter only first characters of name and surname.
This is a part of a simple program for IT classes.

Comment: @defozo: fair enough. Maybe the member names could be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your realloc() size is wrong, you want number_of_friends multiplied by the size of a person struct (I'm guessing):

```
ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends*sizeof(person));
```

Edit: Also this is going to crash after the first loop:

```
number_of_friends++;
ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends);
```

Since number_of_friends starts at 0

Comment: The program crashes after entering 3 people.

Comment: Because you start of "number_of_friends" at 0 instead of 1, and so you write past the end of the array immediately

Comment: Can I leave number_of_frriends=0 and just change the above line to ptr=realloc(ptr, (number_of_friends+1)*sizeof(person)); ?

Answer (score 1):

```
number_of_friends++;
ptr=realloc(ptr, number_of_friends);
```

should be

```
person *tmp = realloc( ptr, sizeof *ptr * (number_of_friends + 1) );
if ( tmp )
{
  ptr = tmp;
  number_of_friends++;
}
```

Remember that `realloc`, like `malloc`, takes a number storage units (bytes) as an argument, not number of *elements* of a particular type.  Also, `realloc` will return `NULL` on failure, so you want to preserve your original pointer until you're sure that the `realloc` operation succeeded.  Similarly, you don't want to update `number_of_friends` until after the `realloc` call has completed.